# Error: Unable to write pid file Mosquitto v2.0.3

Tags: linux, mqtt, pid, mosquitto

since I updated Mosquitto v2.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 the users can't connect to the broker.

When I tried to run with `/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` it threw the following message.
`2020-12-22|12:37:02: Error: Unable to write pid file.`

I saw some people had the same problem, so I added `pid_file /var/run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid`  in mosquitto config but the problem did no go away.

I have this in `/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mosquitto MQTT Broker
Documentation=man:mosquitto.conf(5) man:mosquitto(8)
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=main
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto: /var/log/mosquitto
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/run/mosquitto
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto: /var/run/mosquitto

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The mosquitto.conf file is configured as:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883

log_type error
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type debug
log_type all
log_dest topic 
log_type warning

allow_anonymous false
connection_messages true
max_keepalive 10
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%d|%H:%M:%S

password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile

####################################################
# MOSQUITTO LISTENER WITH SLL
####################################################

listener 8883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous false

#PARA BROKER EN PC
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt

#PARA BROKER EN RASPBERRY PI 3
#cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca_pi.crt
#keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server_pi.key
#certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server_pi.crt

tls_version tlsv1.2
```

When I ran systemctl status mosquitto from the terminal, it showed me the following message...

```
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since mar 2020-12-22 13:06:13 -04; 5s ago
     Docs: man:mosquitto(8)
           man:mosquitto.conf(5)
  Process: 22889 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22889 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

dic 22 13:06:13 carmenmoncada systemd[1]:
```

I don't know what is happening, could anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I already found how to solve the issue.

I've managed to get it working too.
I've manually created a directory `/var/run/mosquitto` with ownership to user mosquitto and then the folder and file were created automatically.

```
  sudo mkdir -m 777 mosquitto
```

In mosquitto.conf I set

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid
```

Comment: This will be due to the changes to the way Mosquitto 2.0+ makes [use of root/privileged user](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/migrating-to-2-0/#use-of-rootprivileged-user). There are some notes re the ubuntu packages in [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1950).

Comment: 'world' 'writeable' is not a very good practice.  You should at least try 755 and make sure the directory is owned by your 'mosquitto' user id.

Answer (score 8):

> sudo mkdir -m 777 mosquitto

**Never ever do this please!**

In place try this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mosquitto/ && sudo chown mosquitto: /var/run/mosquitto
```

and put into the /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

```
...
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that pid file should be commented out:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Mosquitto
I had the same error, when trying to run mosquitto with -c flag, so  commenting out solved this error and mosquitto started.